# play m3u8 in videoview on Android

Tags: android, android-videoview, m3u8

I have a strange problem with playing stream in videoview with this code:

> videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("///.m3u8"));

It playing perfectly on my nexus4 phone, but but on other devices(Fly IQ4410, HTC Legend) there is failure of playing video.

Can anyone explain to me why I have such a problem, or is there any other way to play m3u8 files?

Thanks.

Comment: Try This: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783914/playing-m3u8-file-through-https-on-android-2-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also affected by Android version; for version less than 2.3 I am using Vitamio player (open source) to play .m3u8

Comment: It's very strange but with vitamio it works only on nexus4 too. Maybe problem is in source .m3u8 file. Very very strange.

Comment: I don't understand it. I am using .m3u8 stream and its playing nicely without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

In some devices doesn't support video formats like m3u8,.wav. My suggestion is please add  android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in manifest file. after adding this line still video is not playing. please change video format into Mp4 or 3gp and then try again. Best of luck

Comment: what has android:hardwareAccelerated="true" got to do with live streaming? i am nt aware of it thats why asking..